# My localhost is refusing to connect on MacOS

Tags: php, macos, xampp, localhost

I am running XAMPP and trying to test my PHP but cant get my localhost to connect. I have tried directing it to different ports and nothing has improved, i have tried kill httpd and stop the apache control and restarted XAMPP, still no joy. Any advice?

Comment: Did you check the logs after the restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably installed the **virtual machine** version of XAMPP (e.g. `xampp-osx-7.4.4.0-vm.dmg`). It does not run natively on your machine, but inside a box and with its own local network IP address. It cannot be reached via `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` by default, because they only refer to the host system. The guest system should be seen like another machine in the LAN.

You can find the IP address of the guest system in the *General* tab of the XAMPP app. In my case it is `192.168.64.2`. If I enter that in a browser then I get redirected to the XAMPP dashboard (*Welcome to XAMPP for 7.4.4-0*).

You may enable **port forwarding** in the *Network* tab of the XAMPP app. Select `localhost:8080 -> 80 (Over SSH)` and click the *Enable* button. You should then be able to reach the XAMPP dashboard via `localhost:8080`.